# hiding port with a path - nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have kibana running on port 9292 on localhost. What I want to achieve is when i type http://ip_adress/kibana the page from port 9292 will be loaded but path will remain http://ip_address/kibana/index.html#/dashboard/file/default.json what I get instead is http://ip_adress:9292/index.html#/dashboard/file/default.json

here is my code:

```
server {
    ...
    location /kibana {
         return 301 /kibana/;
    }
    location ~ /kibana/(.*) {   
            error_log /var/log/nginx/kibana-error.log debug;
            proxy_pass   http://ip_address:9292/$1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This [similar serverfault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/601041/unable-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-elasticsearch-on-another-server) might help . Note the part `point config.js at http://FQDN:80/ instead of
http://FQDN:9200`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I updated Kibana from 3 to 4 which helped and now I'm using this configuration :

```
upstream kibana {
    server 127.0.0.1:5601;
}
...
location /kibana {
    return 301 /kibana/;
   }
   location ~ /kibana/(.*) {    
    proxy_pass   http://kibana/$1;
 }
```